# Stash away committed changes

Tags: git

I have made some changes to a local repository and would like to commit these on top of the latest changes to the remote repository. Normally, I could do something like:

```sh
# Stash away my changes
git stash
# Fetch and apply the remote changes.  I do not want a merge.
git fetch
git checkout
# Apply my changes on top of the remote changes
git stash pop
# Commit and push
git add changed.txt
git commit
git push
```

But now I made the mistake of committing my changes. Is there an easy way of stashing away my *commited* changes for a while, like `git stash` does for uncommitted changes?

Answer (score 2):

No need to stash. You can use `git rebase` to achieve what you're after:

```
$ git fetch
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git push
```

This will automatically replay your changes on top of the remote branch.